# Ruby on Rails - How do I create a button to increase an attribute by one every time it is pressed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, button

I'm trying to create a comment section in a website that has an upvoting system where below each comment there is an upVote button that increases the upVote attribute in the comment entity by one.

This is the method I made in my comment model

```
def up_vote(comment)
 if !comment.nil?
    comment.upVote = comment.upVote + 1
  end
end
```

This is the follow up code in my comment controller

```
def up_vote
@comment = Comment.all
    @comment.each do |c|
        c.up_vote(c)
        c.save
    end

end
```

I then added it to my routes

```
get 'up_vote', :to=>'comments#up_vote'
```

And finally this is the code in my show.html of where I want to display the button

```
<%=button_to'Up Vote', up_vote, :method => :get %></p>
```

It won't work when I try to access the page and I have no idea why. Any help on my syntax or if anything about the way I'm calling certain things would be very much appreciated

Comment: We can't really help you without knowing what error you're receiving. Please post the exception and stacktrace.

Comment: is `def up_vote(comment)` defined in the `comment` model? Where is `comment.upVote` defined?

Comment: ArgumentError in Forums#show
Showing Z:/railsproject/gameweb/app/views/forums/show.html.erb where line #27 raised:

wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
Rails.root: Z:/railsproject/gameweb

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/comment.rb:5:in `up_vote'
app/views/forums/show.html.erb:27:in `block in _app_views_forums_show_html_erb___1058566651_89725152'
app/views/forums/show.html.erb:24:in `each'
app/views/forums/show.html.erb:24:in `_app_views_forums_show_html_erb___1058566651_89725152'

Comment: And yes def up_vote(comment is definied in the comment model. upVote is an attribute in the entity Comment so every comment has upVotes as an integer variable

Comment: Checkout from scratch implementation of [reputation system](http://railscasts.com/episodes/364-active-record-reputation-system?autoplay=true). if your still stuck

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
<%=button_to'Up Vote', up_vote, :method => :get %></p>
```

The `up_vote` part should be `up_vote_path`. You might have to name your route:

```
get 'up_vote', :to=>'comments#up_vote', as: :up_vote
```

Comment: Yea I changed the code on the button to                                                <%=button_to'Up Vote', comment.up_vote, method: :get %>                              I'm getting a wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) error now though...

Comment: The second argument to `button_to` needs to be a route name. You're actually calling `commend.up_vote`. You need to use the route name to you controller action, the action will then be the one that calls `comment.up_vote`

Answer (score 0):

The whole architecture you`ve build is wrong, pal. Let me explain why it is so.

First of all - you shall not pass data in database using GET method. It is only for receiving data, not for sending it to be saved. In this case your method should be PUT or PATCH, which purpose is to update data as in such case. Guide to the RESTful HTTP actions: http://restful-api-design.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html
For your code yo fulfit it's aims properly, you ought to change your upvoting routes to:

```
resourses :comments do
    put 'up_vote' # updated to new hash syntax for symbols
end
```

Wrap your route into the resourses instead of writing it indepently, it is a better practice that leads to less mess than your way. **Note:** all the routes written this way are by default memeber routes and equivalent to route with as: :memeber passed into its arguments.

Also change your button to:

```
<p><%=button_to'Up Vote', up_vote_comment_path(comment), :method => :put %></p> <--!dont forget to enclose your HTML tags-->
```

I presume you use this in a each block, so place whatever you called your comment in it the upvote_comment_path parenthesis.

Second - I consider you should upvote specific comment by pressing this button, not all of them, so your controller code must be changed to:

```
def up_vote
 @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
 @comment.upvote
 redirect to comments_path # or which path your comments page is located
end
```

Read this to understand the concept of controller cooked right: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Third, the model. If you call a method on a models object - there's no reason to check if it is nil, beacause you already know it's not, 'cause you already in it's context. If there were no comment - you would not reach the method code, getting NoMethodError on Nil class. The same about passing a comment argument in it`s method - you already have context of it, you don't need to pass it. Following code should help you a bit:

```
def upvote
 upVote += 1
 save
end
```

Fouth and the last - considering your code, I must say that you have a poor knowledge of OOP concepts and Ruby at all, so first of all Google this things before writing more code. Good luck and no mess for you, pal.
More links for God of Links and also for you tu learn some more about OOP and stuff:

- Object model in Ruby and OPP https://launchschool.com/books/oo_ruby/read/the_object_model
- Models
  https://betterexplained.com/articles/intermediate-rails-understanding-models-views-and-controllers/